# Selecting the grouping Key in an Entity Framework query that groups by anonymous type ends up returning one key per grouped object

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have this table

```
ID        Name        City    ... more columns
----------------------------------------------
1         Nate        Boston  ...
2         John        Boston  ...
2         John        Boston  ...
3         Sam         Austin  ...
```

(for reasons beyond my control, ID is duplicated in some cases)

and I have an entity framework model setup for this, in general its working pretty well. I am having an issue while trying to get a unique list.

```
var result = db.table.GroupBy(t => new
    {
        ID = t.ID,
        Name = t.Name,
        City = t.City
    }).Select(g => g.Key)
```

Problem is, this query returns the following:

```
ID        Name        City    
-----------------------------
1         Nate        Boston
2         John        Boston
2         John        Boston 
3         Sam         Austin
```

I thought I was going crazy, so I fired up LinqPad, ran the same query and got my expected results:

```
ID        Name        City   
-----------------------------
1         Nate        Boston
2         John        Boston
3         Sam         Austin
```

I realized that with LinqPad I was connected to my database with Linq-To-SQL, not using the EntityFramework providers for LinqPad. When I connect LinqPad through my assembly, using EntityFramework, I get the same results as in my real project.

What am I missing that is causing Entity Framework and Linq-To-SQL to return different results for the same query and **how can I get the same results as Linq-To-SQL?**

*I should point out that in LinqPad, if I remove the `.Select(g => g.Key);` The results are displayed in the quick view as expected (Key is unique per grouping, and the 2, John, Boston record has two child elements).*

---

For reference, the generated SQL.

This is the generated SQL from Linq-To-SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[City]
FROM [Table] AS [t0]
GROUP BY [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[City]
```

This is the generated SQL from Entity Framework:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City]
FROM (SELECT 
[Table].* -- I changed this to .* because EF code listed all column in table explicitly
FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Table]) AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: I'm curious, if you remove the ID parameter from the query do you get what should be correct results or still are there duplicates?

Comment: Also, adding a Distinct() at the end does not solve your problem?

Comment: @Gusman `.Distinct()` does not help; however, removing the ID from the group by does return a single row as expected. Any idea why having the ID causes the duplicates?

Comment: Then something is messing the EntityKey, don't know exactly what, but I assume it's happening because ID is being used as the EntityKey and it allows duplicated values. Does your table have any unique field? if yes, then changing the EntityKey from ID to that attribute can solve the problem.

Comment: Sadly, the only unique combination is these three fields. (In my sample data ID:2 is the same, but it might not always be the same across all rows sharing ID=2). Any idea why the same query works OK in Linq-To-SQL (via LinqPad)?

Comment: Without analyzing the SQL generated query is really difficult to say, maybe can you get the executed query from the db server?

Comment: It sounds to me like your database is not suitable to be used by Entity Framework.  EF requires all rows in a table to have a unique primary key (this can be a compound key, but it must still be a primary key).  If your database does not have this, then you are going to have issues like these.

Comment: Thanks for the input, looks like an EF optimization or issue (due to the database). I found a solution to my problem with your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gusman lead me to the solution. To the EntityKey issue got me thinking that it must be an Entity Framework thing having something to do with the comparison of the ID going wrong since there are duplicates.

I re-wrote the query as follows, using Linq-To-Objects and I do get the expected results. The key here is to perform the `.GroupBy(...)` after the `.ToList()` so the values are compared in memory, where C# rules are used instead of database or entity framework comparison rules.

```
var result = db.table
.Select(t =>
{
    ID = t.ID,
    Name = t.Name,
    City = t.City
})        // project only used columns, to reduce data from db => web server
.ToList() // convert from Linq-To-Entities, to Linq-To-Objects
.GroupBy(t => new
{
    ID = t.ID,
    Name = t.Name,
    City = t.City
})
.Select(g => g.Key)
```

I'm presuming this is some sort of Entity Framework optimization (that Linq-To-SQL does not do) that in my case of duplicate IDs is back firing.

Since I needed to enumerate all returned data anyway, the `.ToList()` call is not so bad for me. My table is pretty wide though, so I performed the additional `.Select(t => new { ... })` to reduce the number of columns returned from the database server, since I wont benefit from lazy loading after the `.ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks man, your comments were really helpful and lead me to the solution.